# JDBC StatementInspector view bound query parameters

Tags: jdbc, spring-jdbc

Using `org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.spi.StatementInspector`'s `inspect` method, is it possible to see the actual bound parameters of inspected queries.

Currently my `StatementInspector`'s `inspect(String sql)` method only intercepts `INSERT INTO table (value_one, value_two) VALUES (?, ?)` as a SQL string input, but I want it to intercept `INSERT INTO table (value_one, value_two) VALUES ('one', 'two')`.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish this by creating a component that implements HibernatePropertiesCustomizer, and passing in "CRITERIA_VALUE_HANDLING_MODE" as "ValueHandlingMode.INLINE".

However, this will (as the name says) "inline" the parameters into the SQL statement. I'm not sure if Hibernate does any sanitizing on the parameters, so it may open you up to SQL injection.
In my case, this was not an issue, because I only use it for testing purposes, so I did not dig deeper.

Here is the code I used:

```java
@Component
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class CurrentSQL implements HibernatePropertiesCustomizer {
  private List<String> sqls = new ArrayList<>();

  public List<String> getSqls() {
    return sqls;
  }

  public void clearStatements() {
    this.sqls.clear();
  }

  @Override
  public void customize(Map<String, Object> hibernateProperties) {
    hibernateProperties.put(AvailableSettings.CRITERIA_VALUE_HANDLING_MODE, ValueHandlingMode.INLINE);
    hibernateProperties.put(AvailableSettings.STATEMENT_INSPECTOR, (StatementInspector) sql -> {
      this.sqls.add(sql);
      return sql;
    });
  }
}
```

Then, in my tests, I do something like this:

```java
currentSQL.clearStatements();
repository.runSomeMethodThatGeneratesSQL();
var sql = currentSQL.getSqls().get(0);
```